# Where does this feature request/fix of filtering when uploading files belong?

Tags: chrome, mime-types, upload

Using a R-shiny app in Ubuntu, with a field to upload an `.Rmd` file,
that has a filter for file extension:

```
# R-shiny code
fileInput("id",
  "label",
  accept = c(
    ".Rmd" # this fails the same way as: ".Rmd", ".rmd", ".RMD" 
  )
)
```

```html
# html produced by R
<input id="file_input_id" 
class="shiny-input-file shiny-bound-input" 
type="file" 
accept=".Rmd,.rmd,.RMD">
```

Ubuntu's Chrome file selector shows only: `.rmd`, and `.RMD` files in the file selector window.
[image]

In Windows this problem does not happen for obvious reasons.
In Mac Chrome, the problem does not happen

`.Rmd` is the common way to write that extension, so, it would be desirable to show those files when filtering.

<s>This seems to depend on mimetypes, or nautilus (Gnome)</s>

Looking in https://mimetype.io/all-types, R-markdown, .Rmd is not defined.

So, I wonder what could be a next step to allow linux to show/filter `.Rmd` files, in addition to `.rmd` and `.RMD` when uploading files to a site

Comment: I've voted to close this question as it's not a Unix or Linux question. It's a programming question and belongs on Stack Overflow and needs to be moved there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the conversation in:

https://discourse.gnome.org/t/is-this-feature-request-combined-uppercase-lowercase-extension-filter-nautilus-related/18565

this depends on the browser, actually it happens on Chrome but not in Firefox.
In Opera, it doesn't happen in the pre-upload file picker (which shows recent downloads). But it happens in the common file picker.

Firefox ok:
[image: ok in firefox]